# Powerpivot using If function

Tags: powerpivot

I have a table that contains text values in several columns. One column has a text value of either true or false. The data type of this column is Text.
Now I want to add a measure that calculates the rows where the column has a value of true. I am using an IF function:

```
=IF(Table[column a] = "true", COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(columnid)),0)
```

When doing this, I am getting an error saying that the value cannot be determined in this context. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a measure that has a context of several rows rather than 1 row, so it can't determine the true/false test in your if statement.  Try this DAX for your calculated measure:

```
MyMeasure:= Calculate(DistinctCount(Table[columnid]), Table[column a] = "True")
```

Here's a good article on the CALCULATE function in DAX: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2010/01/03/how-calculate-works-in-dax.aspx